# Crear un formulario en Google Sheets para que otras personas lo diligencien

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Deseo crear un formulario de afiliación en una hoja de calculo de Google, para que otras personas las diligencien.  Algo similar a un Google Form, pero en lugar de enviar una encuesta, enviar un formulario de hoja de cálculo. ¿Habrá alguna forma de hacerlo?

Lo único que logro es crear un google form y guardar las respuestas en el archivo de hoja de cálculo de Google

Este es el formulario que deseo enviar a resolver :

https://ibb.co/KWL3v62

esto es lo que consigo.

https://ibb.co/HBhgDNq

Comment: Es mejor agregar las imágenes usando la herramienta propia de este sitio, así se pueden mostrar en línea con el texto y sin "ruido" en lugar de montarlas en otros espacio y poner el enlace a la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

En la hoja de cálculo dar formato a las celdas aplicando color, borders, uniendo celdas etc.

Luego crea una copia para cada usuario que lo vaya a "diligenciar"

Ten en cuenta que si compartes el mismo archivo por las características de colaboración en tiempo real podría haber "colisiones" de ediciones (varios usuarios editen la misma celda de forma prácticamente simultánea) o bien que un usuario modifique los datos capturados por otro antes de que se hayan transferido los datos a la hoja de cálculo que vaya a fungir como base de datos.

Luego para pasar los datos registrados en cada "formulario" podrías usar la función IMPORTRANGE (sería muy complicado), Google Apps Script o la API de Google Sheets.